# Block Programs When RDPed

Tags: windows, rdp

Is there a way for System/Windows Administrator to block certain programs from running when user is RDPed into a machine.

What I am trying to ask is I need a way to block a user from accessing certain webpages or using RDP client to RDP into another jump server vs. permit everything when the person is physically in front of the machine.

I hope I clearly explained my question, if not let me know and I will try to elaborate more.

Thanks

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? This sounds like a classic example where you'd want to educate your users, rather than block them. What you're asking for is probably possible by having lots of GPO-wizardry.

Comment: They are critical infrastructure support team. My goal is to block certain programs from running or deny access to certain information when support engineer remotes into his desktop. Everything is permitted when engineer is in front of the machine.

Comment: You still don't explain why. Wouldn't it be easier to just set up a separate RDP box (and disallow RDP on others)? You could then secure this one box.